# Two versions of AM-GM inequality

Tags: a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I'm currently studying functional analysis and in the preliminary chapter the author gives the following inequality:

> **AM-GM Inequality:**
>
> Let $x,y>0$ and $0< \lambda <1$. Then $$x^\lambda y^{1-\lambda} \leq \lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y$$

But I know the AM-GM Inequality of two positive numbers $x$ and $y$ is $$\sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{x+y}{2}$$

But the first version is different. What is the difference between these two versions? Actually the latter one is the special case of the first one, namely, putting $\lambda =1/2$. Its ok.

So, why the author gives that name for the first one? Is there anything special about the first one?

Any help? and thanks in advance

Comment: The first one is weighted AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Maybe you mean $x^\lambda y^{1-\lambda}$ in the LHS.

Comment: yes! sorry! I edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the logarithm, your inequality is equivalent to 
$$\lambda \ln(x) + (1-\lambda) \ln(y) \leq \ln (\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)$$

which expresses the fact that $\ln$ is concave.

The classical AM-GM inequality expresses this concavity in the special case where you are considering the middle point between $x$ and $y$. But of course the concavity is true for every convex combination of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Is there any other intuition behind this?

Comment: By "exprimes," do you mean "expresses"?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English !... I edited.